# Make a layer respond to two modifier keys being pressed in QMK

Tags: qmk, qmk-firmware

In a QMK firmware configuration, I can map a single modifier key to a new keymap layer using [MO(x)](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware/blob/master/docs/feature_layers.md#switching-and-toggling-layers).

How can I do this such that two modifier keys must be pressed simultaneously?

Example:  I would like to map <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to generate a Unicode delta, <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to generate a Unicode epsilon, etc.

Comment: Do you already have that target layer, e. g. a greek letter layer, or are you looking to have only a couple of unicode symbols? Also, I'm not sure you can use [Fn] for this without some complications as it's not clear which keycode exactly is associated with it.

Comment: The requirement for three keys is not necessary when [tap dancing](https://thomasbaart.nl/2018/12/13/qmk-basics-tap-dance/) is available. Here is [an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZgZwZE4s_A&t=2m35s).

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your specific code into the custom Quantum function `process_record_user`:

```
bool process_record_user(uint16_t keycode, keyrecord_t *record) {
    // enter your code for [Fn][Ctrl]-[α] here
    return true;
}
```

You can try the **Quantum** tab in the [Firmware Builder](https://kbfirmware.com/). Even if it is end-of-life, you'll see, what is meant.

You can also set `UNICODEMAP_ENABLE = yes` and use the [Unicode Map](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/feature_unicode?id=unicode-map).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do (half) the trick:

In function `layer_state_set_user`, check for layer Fn (some bit arithmetic similar to [update_tri_layer_state](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware/blob/da280739efa1d23346f9540044b8689a31ca8689/quantum/quantum.c#L376)) and the Ctrl state (`get_mods() & MOD_MASK_CTRL`). When in Fn layer and Ctrl is down, deactivate Ctrl (`del_mods(MOD_MASK_CTRL)`) and return `state | x`; otherwise return `state & ~x`.

Unfortunately, this will probably require Ctrl to be pressed before Fn.

At least that's what happens in my similar shift + layer _L4 => layer _S_L4 implementation in [my keymap](https://github.com/mkq/qmk_firmware/blob/6384b62baa323be50b407d42dbae224df96fa758/keyboards/xbows/nature/keymaps/mkq/keymap.c#L63). It requires shift to be pressed before `LT(_L4,…)`.

For the other direction (_L4 + shift => _S_L4), I have `MO(_S_L4)` on the shift keys in layer _L4, but that is somehow disabled by my `layer_state_set_user`.

Answer (score 0):

What should "Fn + E" and "Fn + D" do (when Ctrl is not held)? For sake of example, I'll assume you want them to do PgUp and PgDn.

Here is how I would go about implementing this:

1. **Enable Unicode input**: In rules.mk, add `UNICODEMAP_ENABLE = yes`. In config.h, add `#define UNICODE_SELECTED_MODES UC_WINC` if you are on Windows. See the [Unicode documentation](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/feature_unicode) for other OSs and options.
2. Define an "Fn" layer in the keymap.
3. Define a couple custom keycodes, and place them in the Fn layer at the `d` and `e` positions.
4. Handle the custom keys in `process_record_user()`, using `get_mods()` to test whether Ctrl is held. See also [macros that respond to mods](https://getreuer.info/posts/keyboards/macros/index.html#macros-that-respond-to-mods). Then use `send_unicode_string()` to type the Unicode symbol itself.

Code sketch:

```c
// Copyright 2022 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

enum layers { BASE, FN, /* Other layers... */ }; 

enum custom_keycodes {
  UPDIR = SAFE_RANGE,
  FN_E,
  FN_D,
  // Other custom keys...
};

const uint16_t keymaps[][MATRIX_ROWS][MATRIX_COLS] PROGMEM = {
  [BASE] = LAYOUT(...),
  [FN] = LAYOUT(..., FN_E, ..., FN_D, ...),
  ...
};

const uint32_t unicode_map[] PROGMEM = {};

static void symbol_key(uint16_t* registered_key,
                       keyrecord_t* record,
                       uint16_t default_keycode,
                       const char* symbol,
                       const char* uppercase_symbol) {
  if (record->event.pressed) {  // On key press.
    const uint8_t mods = get_mods();
    const bool ctrl_held = (mods & MOD_MASK_CTRL) != 0;
    const bool shifted = (mods & MOD_MASK_SHIFT) != 0;

    if (ctrl_held) {  // Is the Ctrl mod held?
      unregister_mods(MOD_MASK_CTRL);  // Clear the Ctrl mod.
      // Type Unicode symbol according to whether shift is active.
      send_unicode_string(shifted ? uppercase_symbol : symbol);
      *registered_key = KC_NO;
    } else {
      *registered_key = default_keycode;
      register_code16(*registered_key);
    }
  } else {  // On key release.
    unregister_code16(*registered_key);
    *registered_key = KC_NO;
  } 
}

bool process_record_user(uint16_t keycode, keyrecord_t* record) {
  const uint8_t mods = get_mods();
  const bool ctrl_held = (mods & MOD_MASK_CTRL) != 0;
  const bool shifted = (mods & MOD_MASK_SHIFT) != 0;
  
  switch (keycode) {
    case FN_E: {
      static uint16_t registered_key = KC_NO;
      symbol_key(&registered_key, record, KC_PGUP, "ε", "Ε");
    } return false;  
    case FN_D: {
      static uint16_t registered_key = KC_NO;
      symbol_key(&registered_key, record, KC_PGDN, "δ", "Δ");
    } return false;  
  }
  return true;
}
```